# button_to disabled: true doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

Maybe I misunderstood something..?

button_to signature:

> button_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)

My button:

```
<%= button_to "Re-send pin", {action: "send_pin_again", :disabled => true} %>
```

is still enabled..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe I misunderstood something

Yes, `disabled` is [an html attribute](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to).

> There are a few special `html_options`:
>
> ...
>
> `:disabled` - If set to `true`, it will generate a disabled button.

Place it in the corresponding argument.

```
 <%= button_to "Re-send pin", {action: "send_pin_again"}, :disabled => true %>
```

Comment: Sorry, doesnt. work. I just tried it again.. `<%= button_to "Re-send pin", {action: "send_pin_again"}, :disabled => true %>` Cant imagine where is the glich.. I investigate with dev tools - disabled isnt added..

Comment: Just to clarify - I add it in simple form partial. I restarted server and even tried with -   `<%= button_to "Re-send pin", {}, :disabled => true %>`

Comment: @PlanB: must be your server requires restart or it is otherwise [a caching issue](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/). `disabled` most certainly belongs in the third argument.

Comment: But i restarted server... Will try few more times. Its a ridiculous problem I cant get rid of...

Comment: @PlanB: maybe it's browser cache somehow. Or rails cache. Try clearing those too. :shrug:

Comment: I wont say what happend

Comment: @PlanB: no-no, you __must__ say! Were you hitting the wrong server? :)

Comment: I wil NEVER say

Comment: C'mon @JuliusDzidzevičius, what am I doing wrong? I've just run into this issue, years later... EDIT: turns out, moving `disabled` before other attributes works.